# Python requests library, sending a post, get, authenticating and downloading files

Tags: python, post, oauth, python-requests, get

I am trying to automatically download many invoices. These invoices are pdf files generated/stored by a shop website. The current "workflow" that one has to go through looks like this:

```
1. Go to the website 
2. Login 
3. Possibly redirect to another URL (sometimes manually) 
4. Press a JScript button ("orders")
5. Press aonther JScript button ("download PDF") 
6. Repeat 5 for every PDF file that exists (invoice that exists)
```

What I want to do is use Python 3.9 + the requests library to automatically download all PDF files into a folder by using the API. I have so far managed to successfully login using POST - I know this because I get an email whenever I log in to the account, so when I run my script I also get an Email whenever I supposedly logged in. However at this point I am stuck. The shop itself has an API (which isn't official) and I can't seem to GET from it (I get a 401 error) even though I can successfully log in.

I assume that this is because the shop uses access tokens/cookies which I can view in my browser but I can not figure out how to retrieve/send them with my script. The shop uses OAUTH. Is there a standard way to deal with OAUTH cookie/access tokens?

This is my script so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

#URLS
url1= 'https://login.migros.ch/login'
url2= 'https://shop.migros.ch/shopping/public/v1/api/orders/ids'
url3= 'https://shop.migros.ch/customer/public/v1/api/users/self/reporting/INVOICE/en/orders/ORDERID(changed)'

#HEADERS GET + CSRF token
headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'
    
}
get = s.get(url1, headers=headers, verify=False)

#print(get.text)


soup = BeautifulSoup(get.text, 'lxml')
csrf_token = soup.select_one('meta[name="_csrf"]')['content']
#print(csrf_token)


#LOGIN INFO
payload = {'username': 'myusername', 'password': 'mypassword', '_csrf': csrf_token}

#HEADERS POST

post = s.post(url1, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
#print(post.json)
#print(post.headers)
response = s.get(url1)
#print(response.headers)
get = s.get(url2, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
#print(get)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.